# redis v4 list sorted in reverse order

Tags: node.js, redis, nestjs

I am trying to get a list in reverse score order.

I am using node redis v4.0.1 which no longer supports client.ZREVRANGEBYSCORE

If I try await client.zRangeByScoreWithScores('rankings', '-inf', '+inf');
This produces a list in ascending order.
If I try await client.zRange('rankings', '-inf', '+inf', {
BY: 'SCORE',
REV: true,
});
There is an empty list produced.

How do I get a list in reverse score order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you're looking for [`ZRANGEBYSCORE`](https://redis.io/commands/zrangebyscore), not the 'rev' one.

So `ZRANGEBYSCORE -inf +inf`

Comment: I don't think you can get the same output with `ZREVRANGEBYSCORE`

Answer (score 0):

Try doing the following:

```
await client.zRange('rankings', '+inf', '-inf', { BY: 'SCORE', REV: true, });
```

When I checked out the documentation, you should switch min and max if you set REV to true.

Answer (score 0):

node redis v4.0 and the above version we use as below.

```
client.sendCommand(['ZREVRANGEBYSCORE', 'players', '+inf', '-inf', 'WITHSCORES', 'LIMIT', '0', '3']).then(res => {
    console.log(res);
})
```